# javascript image does not show

Tags: javascript

I cannot quite understand why my background-image is not working in my javascript.

The background picture is located here:

[Background Picture](https://vouzalis.com/images/background/bg2.jpg)

and it should be on the following site:

[My Portfolio](https://vouzalis.com/index.php)

Is there something wrong with the syntax? When I run on my localhost the backgroundpicture is showing fine, but as soon as it set it online and change to the path: https://vouzalis.com/images/background/bg2.jpg , it is not working.

The whole javascript code can be seen here:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a73bp2hk/)

```
{image : 'https://vouzalis.com/images/background/bg2.jpg'},
        {image : 'https://vouzalis.com/images/background/bg2.jpg'},
        {image : 'https://vouzalis.com/images/background/bg2.jpg'}                                                                                  
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your jsfiddle doesn't load jQuery or Supersized. Use "External Resources".
2. Your site includes them with:

   `<link rel="..."/>`

   Use:

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>`